# Pivot table but not using table id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Is it possible to make a Pivot Table without using table id?

**users**

```
id
biometric_id
first_name
last_name
```

**attendances**

```
id
biometric_id
date
emp_in
emp_out
```

**user_attendances**

```
user_id
attendances_biometrics_id
```

I wanted to ask if this is available to link it like this? Because I need to show the attendance of the user that has his biometrics.

If it is possible, how?

Comment: Does ```biometric_id``` in the attendances table have a unique constraint on it? It would need to if you wanted a foreign key constraint on it.

Comment: @CUGreen yes the biometric_id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If `attendances.biometric_id` has a unique constraint on it then there should be no reason why you cannot use it as a foreign key constraint.

Assuming your tables have been setup properly with foreign key constraints, your user model would probably have something like this:

```
public function attendances() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attendances', 'user_attendances', 'user_id', 'attendances_biometrics_id');
}
```